# PostgreSQL: One database to multiple user

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.3 version. I have created database name `db1` now I need it to share with other users who all are connected with the LAN's to connect other applications with the same database.

**In SQL Server**:   We can do this by selecting server name with login details.

[image]

**Question**:

- Is it possible in PostgreSQL?
- If yes, how can do this?
- What is the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow remote connections to the database. Information about `pg_hba.conf` can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

After that, you can connect programatically with a connection string, or similar to your image, with a GUI application like [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/).

To connect (remotely or locally) from pgAdmin choose ***File -> Add Server...*** and enter the connection information into the dialog box. Here's an example of the window:

[image: example of add server window]

Your client computers will also need to have PostgreSQL drivers as well. If you're doing this in Windows, you'll probably be using ODBC. The PostgreSQL ODBC drivers are [here](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).  Info on the connection string format can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/).

Here's an example of what pgAdmin looks like:

[image: pgAdmin]

Comment: Thanks. Can you put some image of GUI like pgAdmin?

Comment: Yup! I have ODBC drivers.

Comment: Sorry! But I am still confusing about this. What is that function `gin_extract_trgm` does?

Comment: It's just a random example image from Google image search. If you mean what is the window, it looks like it's a properties window for a function. It allows the user to define a function (similar or maybe the same as a "stored procedure") using the GUI. The function itself is not shown, so I have no idea what it does. (Googling it, it seems to be a part of Postgres itself).

Comment: Okay! But I want to see the window or GUI through which we connect to other server from other system.